# How do l reload or refresh the contents of a jtree in java

Tags: java, jtree

l wrote a program to list the folders in an active directory. l have two jtrees,
A - to list the computers on the network;
B - to list the folders in the PC selected in tree A.
But whenever l first select a node in tree A, it normally fills tree B, but whenever l select another node in tree A, B doesn't reload to show the contents of the new node.
How can l make tree B to change content base on the last selected node in tree A?

i have tried

```
jTree2.setModel(null);
```

and

```
DefaultTreeModel defMod = (DefaultTreeModel)jTree2.getModel();
defMod.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fire a `TreeModelEvent`, to signal changes in the `TreeModel`.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treemodellistener.html